# Is there a way to force Notepad++ to always insert the set number of spaces when I press tab?

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, I have it set to insert 4 spaces instead of tab. I am working in a file format (robot framework) where it is important that some things be separated by multiple (more than 1) spaces.

Notepad++, when I push tab, will *first* move the cursor however many of spaces to get to the next multiple of 4, i.e., trying to automatically keep everything lined up, and *then* tab 4 spaces after. If it just so happens that the last thing I typed ends 1 space character away from the next aligned position, when I tab, it only puts in that single space...and my automation fails. (If it happens to be 2, 3, or 4 spaces away, those cases all work, but really for consistency, it would be nice if 'tab' always meant '4 spaces from the current cursor position'.)

Is there a way to make Notepad++ ignore alignment and always, no matter what, insert exactly 4 spaces if I press tab? I want to preserve auto-indent functionality, but I don't think that should matter for what I'm asking. I'm sure there has to be some setting somewhere that does this, but I'm at a loss on where to look for it.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible (without modifying the source code) as it is a requirement that is need by probably zero other people.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'll gladly prove you wrong then. :)

Comment: @LPChip lol. Well done ;) I wonder what functionality that macro will break ...

Comment: @DavidPostill it breaks Scintilla command: SCI_TAB. whatever that is. :) And in the scintilla tab, you can actually give that a different key to resolve the conflict.

Comment: @LPChip Hmm. [scintilla](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Notepad%2B%2B_And_Scintilla) - and I've never seen a Scintilla tab whatever that is ... not that I care, because I'm not going to redefine <tab>, but it might affect the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. New versions of Notepad++ offer the macro recording tool, which you can use to bind common tasks to a key.

What you want to do is start a new macro recording, and press space 4 times, then stop the recording.

Then press Macro->Save Macro, select TAB as the key and give it a name.

It will say at the bottom: key found, but it will still work.

Now, every time you press tab, it will insert 4 spaces instead of a tab.

Alternatively you can bind it to a different keyboard combination, such as ctrl-tab so you have both options.

Comment: ctrl+tab is used to switch between tabs ...

Comment: Yeah, it was just meant as an example. :)